# How to put the dots in the centre?

Tags: pdftex, align

```
\documentclass[10pt,a4paper]{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{amsfonts}
\usepackage{amssymb}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\begin{document}
    A+B
    \\
    C+D
    \\
    D+E
    \\
    \vdots
    \\Y+Z
\end{document}
```

I want the output like the dots should be placed below the plus sign.
But i am getting the dots aligned to the left, how can I fix it.

Sample Output:
[image]

Can someone please help me out?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's a way to this :

```
\begin{document}
$\begin{array}{l@{~}c@{~}l}
A &+     &B\\
C &+     &D\\
  &\vdots&\\
E &+     &F
\end{array}$
\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 3):

One way is use `matrix` as defined in `amsmath` package:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}

\begin{document}
    \[
\begin{matrix}
A   +   B   \\
B   +   C   \\
  \vdots    \\[3pt]
Y   +   Z
\end{matrix}
    \]
\end{document}
```

[image]

or with `array` (based on the last solution stolen from deleted @campa answer):

```
\documentclass{article}

\begin{document}
    \[
\begin{array}[t]{r@{\:}c@{\:}l}
A & +   & B     \\
B & +   & C     \\
& \vdots  &     \\[3pt]
Y & +   & Z   \\
\end{array}    
    \]
\end{document}
```

Result is in this particular case similar as before, however, now terms on left and right from + can have different lengths but math expressions are still centered at + sign.

[image]

Comment: To be fussy `\;` inserts `\thickmuskip` while around a mathbin we have `\medmuskip`, so `\:` should be more appropriate. But +1 anyway `:-)`

Comment: @campa, you are right. Thank you for pointing this. Implemented in answer! BTW, why you delete your answer. It is very good one!

Comment: I was puzzled by something related to the two `mathtools`-based solutions and I was afraid of having misinterpreted the macros. I didn't like the idea of a possibly wrong answer so I deleted it in order to think about it later. Then time passed and I completely forgot about it...